# Is it possible to get "instancecount" from user and create ec2 instance accordingly by using Cloud formation template.?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I understand that it is not possible to use NumberofInstance property in Cloudformation, I have used "DesiredCapacity" in AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup, But I would like to know if there is any alternative for this, like using iteration inside the template

or use customer scripts under user data to create identical instances

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, although the [EC2 RunInstances API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) supports launching multiple EC2 instances (via **MaxCount/MinCount** parameters), the [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) CloudFormation resource only allows you to create a single EC2 instance at a time (see also [this forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=338479#338479) for confirmation from ChrisW@AWS on this limitation).

In addition, iteration inside the template is not possible using CloudFormation's [Intrinsic Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html), so that is not an option either.

As an alternative, I would recommend using an intermediate template format, then compile down to a CloudFormation-template (JSON or YML) using a preprocessor when greater expressive power is needed. You can use a full-featured library like [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere), but it's also easy enough to code up your own basic preprocessing layer to suit your use-case and programming-language/library preferences.

My current choice is embedded Ruby ([ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)), mostly because I'm already familiar with it. Here's an example `template.yml.erb` file using iteration that generates a CloudFormation YAML:

```
Resources:
<% (1..5).each do |i| -%>
  Instance<%=i%>:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    # ...etc etc...
<% end -%>
```

To process, run `cat template.yml.erb | | ruby -rerb -e "puts ERB.new(ARGF.read, nil, '-').result" > template.yml`, which will write the following CloudFormation-ready template to `template.yml`:

```
Resources:
  Instance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    # ...etc etc...
  Instance2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    # ...etc etc...
  Instance3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    # ...etc etc...
  Instance4:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    # ...etc etc...
  Instance5:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    # ...etc etc...
```

I've used this technique to help manage large numbers of resources in complex CloudFormation stacks with good results.

Comment: Hi, in the below JSON template they have created 3 instances. I need to customize the same to create 5 instances. I will get the Number of Instance from user. How can I modify the same.?
https://github.com/stelligent/stelligent_commons/blob/master/cloudformation/codedeploy-ec2.json